# How do I make my virtual host available to public?

Tags: website, wamp, ddns

Im using a WAMP server to host a opencart store and I created a virtual host for it. When I type opencart/ in my browser it points me correctly to my site. So the website is working as I want. I want to make my site accessible to anyone. I want to use a DDNS server for my website. What are the steps I should take to get it up and running and point my DDNS to my virtual host and port? I am currently using DUC (No-ip) for my ddns

Answer (score 0):

ngrok can do this for you: https://ngrok.com/
Install, sign up for an account, and refer to https://ngrok.com/docs#http to set up an http tunnel via ngrok servers.
This youtube video sums up all you need to do : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCxt9SAnkyc

Comment: okay yes, but how do i point ngrok to my opencart/ ? Ive seen forums of people editing a vhost or a similar file, but I dont know what to do

Comment: All you need to do is check on which port wamp server is running, say it's port 8080 :
on your home pc, you access your app via : http://localhost:8080/opencart/
from outside (internet) , http://ngrok_tunnel/opencart